# How to open a folder with GUI from c program?

Tags: c, macos, unix, filesystems, finder

I'm writing a program searching a file in Mac OS filesystem. I would like to how to pop up the GUI folder with finder once my program found the file. Is this possible? Is there any system calls I can using to open a directory with finder? It is written in C

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Some graphical toolkits have widgets to open files or directories. You might also run (on MacOSX) a `system` command using the `open` program (specific to MacOSX) which is rumored to do that.

Comment: `open` is not a rumor. [Apple SE has something about it](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/please-share-your-hidden-os-x-features-or-tips-and-tricks/1349#1349).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the open command. Upvote to compensate an unjust downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the `open` command. You can use `open .` to open the finder window corresponding to the current directory, or `open document.pdf` to open a particular document with its corresponding default application.